# Spark group by - Pig conversion

Tags: apache-spark, apache-pig

I am trying to achieve something like this in spark. The following code snippet is from Pig Latin. Is there anyway I can do the same thing with Spark?

```
    A = load 'student' AS (name:chararray,age:int,gpa:float);
    DESCRIBE A; 

    A: {name: chararray,age: int,gpa: float} DUMP A; (John,18,4.0F)
    (Mary,19,3.8F) (Bill,20,3.9F) (Joe,18,3.8F)

    B = GROUP A BY age;

    Result:  (18,{(John,18,4.0F),(Joe,18,3.8F)}) (19,{(Mary,19,3.8F)})
    (20,{(Bill,20,3.9F)})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to do a list of names by age. I believe the Spark API doesn't allow you to collect complete rows and get a complete row list in the same way.

```
// Input data
val df = {
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    import java.time.LocalDate

    val simpleSchema = StructType(
        StructField("name", StringType) ::
        StructField("age", IntegerType) ::
        StructField("gpa", FloatType) :: Nil)

    val data = List(
        Row("John", 18, 4.0f),
        Row("Mary", 19, 3.8f),
        Row("Bill", 20, 3.9f),
        Row("Joe", 18, 3.8f)
    )    

    spark.createDataFrame(data.asJava, simpleSchema)
}
df.show()
val df2 = df.groupBy(col("age")).agg(collect_list(col("name")))
df2.show()
```

Comment: Is a dataframe really necessary? If you make an RDD of  (age, (person)), then it's a simple groupByKey